# How to sort alphabetical dropdown data on polymer

Tags: polymer

I have a dropdown like this :

```
<div>
  <paper-dropdown-menu label="Speciality">
    <paper-listbox id="selectSpeciality" slot="dropdown-content" attr-for-selected="name" selected="{{doctor.speciality}}" class="dropdown-content">
      <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[specs]]">
        <paper-item name="[[item]]">[[item]]</paper-item>
      </template>
    </paper-listbox>
  </paper-dropdown-menu>
</div>
```

And data like this :

[image: sort]
How to sorting by alpabetical ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to order the categories obtained instead of showing them directly, you can create a function that sorts them or **better** save them already sorted.

Comment: Hi Nuria, I'm newbe on polymer. can you give me an example ?

Comment: as a personal preference I would also have the input as already sorted, maybe even have a separate property computed based on this one, in a very similar way.. but it's also worth noting that the `dom-reapeat` also has a `sort` property in which you can pass the name of a callback that would sort the list https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/api/elements/Polymer.DomRepeat#property-sort

Comment: Hi Nuria, Awesome, Thanks for your hand.

Comment: btw, How to debug on polymer ?

Comment: Well, I use chrome devtools and I put debug breakpoint where I need.

Comment: And mishu, as I said in my response I think that it is better to have this array sorted, adding the items sorted but it depends of the use case that it's not possible.